# bsxfun doesn't work as I expect on a constant function

Tags: matlab

In Matlab R2016a, I have a large set of small X-vectors and Y-vectors which are paired (e.g. 10,000 1x3 X-vectors paired with 10,000 1x3 Y vectors).  For each {X,Y} pair, I want to calculate a 2-scalar-argument function for every pairwise combination of the elements in X and Y, (so in my example I would get 10,000 3x3 matrices).

I thought I could use bsxfun to perform these calculations, but it doesn't work when I try to do some simple tests.  `bsxfun(@(x,y) x*y,[1 2],[1 2]')` returns:

```
ans =

     1     2
     2     4
```

Which is what I would expect.  However, `bsxfun(@(x,y) 1,[1 2],[1 2]')` returns:

```
Error using bsxfun
Specified function handle produces invalid output dimensions. The function handle
must be a binary elementwise function.
```

Which makes no sense.  The function handle *is* a binary elementwise function that always returns the scalar 1, so `bsxfun` should give the same result as `ones(2,2)`, unless I'm not understanding how `bsxfun` works.

Comment: I haven't gotten that far in my code yet.  I usually like for test cases to work before I spend the next hour writing code that depends on a function I haven't used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inputs to the function handle that are passed to `bsxfun` *are not scalars*. In versions prior to R2016b, the inputs are *either* scalar or they are the same size.

> `FUNC` can also be a handle to any binary element-wise function not listed
>       above. A binary element-wise function in the form of `C = FUNC(A,B)`
>       accepts arrays `A` and `B` of arbitrary but equal size and **returns output
>       of the same size**. Each element in the output array `C` is the result
>       of an operation on the corresponding elements of `A` and `B` only. **`FUNC` must
>       also support scalar expansion, such that if `A` or `B` is a scalar, `C` is the
>       result of applying the scalar to every element in the other input array**.

In releases since R2016b, they do not have to be equal sizes, but should be [*compatible sizes*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html)

In the example you have shown, the first input to the function handle is a scalar and the second is a vector (`y`) and the function is evaluated for every element of x and the output is expected to be the size of `y`

In the case you've posted, the call to `bsxfun` is essentially the equivalent of:

```
x = [1 2];
y = [1 2].';

yourfunc = @(x,y)x * y;

for k = 1:numel(x)
    output(:,k) = yourfunc(x(k), y)
end
```

If you want to return a `1` for every entry, you need to replace your function with something that yields the appropriately sized output.

```
bsxfun(@(x,y)ones(max(size(x), size(y))), [1 2], [1 2]')
```

How you formulate the function handle really depends upon your specific problem

Comment: and to quote documentation: "A binary element-wise function of the form C = fun(A,B) accepts arrays A and B of arbitrary, but equal size and **returns output of the same size**."

Comment: But in the example, the arguments aren't the same size?  `[1 2]` is 1x2, while `[1 2]'` is 2x1, but it works for `@(x,y) x*y`

Comment: Also, why the max?  Shouldn't it just be `bsxfun(@(x,y) ones(size(y)),[1 2],[1 2]')`?

Comment: @Frank, the `max` is to support the case of scalar expansion (read the docs!). For example, if `y` is scalar but `x` is a vector, you function will fail as it should return output of the same size as `x`. You can easily see your example fails if you transpose input dimensions: `bsxfun(@(x,y) ones(size(y)),[1 2]',[1 2])`

Comment: @Frank Right it works for `x * y` since `x` in that case is a scalar and `y` is `2 x 1`. And yes, you *could* do what you've proposed for the ones in this specific example, but I was writing an example that would return ones regardless of the inputs.

Comment: @Suever That's so bizarre, though.  Neither one is a scalar, they're both vectors.  I think I can make it work, though

Comment: @Frank I realize that both x and y are vectors but if you look at my explicit expansion into a for loop you'll see that only a single element of x (a scalar) is passed to your anonymous function at once while a vector is passed as the second input.